# codeigniter remember me for login by session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, config

My config.php setting

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

As per docs its working fine, session expiring on browser close.
But what if i want to hold session for 1 year (Remember me feature).

I tried to overwrite settings for remember me. But failed

```
 $new_expiration = (60*60*24*365); //A year milliseconds

 $this->config->set_item('sess_expiration', $new_expiration);
 $this->config->set_item('sess_expire_on_close', FALSE);

 $this->session->sess_expiration = $new_expiration;
 $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = FALSE;
 $this->session->set_userdata('name','virat');
```

Checking code on another file

```
 echo $this->session->userdata('name');
print_r($this->session->userdata());
```

Is there any way to hold session by ignoring default settings?
What i am doing wrong?
Version: CI3

Update ->>
I am still trying to make it happen. I think i found a workaround.
CI updates the session cookie file every time you read the session.

and another problem is CI not update the config.php values simply via $this.

So

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI = & get_instance();
        $this->CI->config->set_item('sess_expiration', 1253);


    }
```

Make direct call to CI itself works. it updates the config.php variable.
another point is you need to do this in every Controller a "single read without config.php overwrite" will erase the cookie values and session values. You can also include it in MY_controller optional.

Comment: why don't you use `cookie` insted.

Comment: session can't hold much. use cookie ...

Comment: I can, But just trying with session, is there any way? also thinking about Cookie + Database, dont want to store user id directly, will save a random unique number to cookie. CI is also offering session via db, Regolith , Abdulla Nilam

Comment: what about `sess_expire_on_close = false`? and what do you mean with "remember me" ? is there some sort of "remember me" checkbox in your login form ?

Comment: @sintakonte , right a checkbox in a form, sess_expire_on_close = false means session will not expire on browser close, it will switch to provided time for session expiry. sess_expire_on_close is in config.php

Comment: yeah ok - but if i click the checkbox remember me - i dont want that my session get lost on browser close because i don't want always login myself just because i close my browser isn't it ? btw i'm just asking because i can provide you a solution but in order to do that - i need to understand what you want :P

Comment: @sintakonte right

Answer (score 0):

alright - i try to explain what i would do - based on your question and those comments

I assume your checkbox name is "autologin" something like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="autologin" value="1" />
```

If someone checks "remember me" and after submitting the credentials, in your Login controller or Model you should do the following:

```
$this->load->helper("cookie");

$autoLogin = $this->input->post("autologin",true);

if ($autoLogin == 1)
{
    $cookie = array(
        'name'   => 'autologin',
        'value'  => '1',
        'expire' => '31536000',
        'path'   => '/'
    );
    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
}
else
{
    delete_cookie("autologin");
}
```

and after that - the only thing you need to change is your config File.

Something like that, should do the trick

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

if ((isset($_COOKIE['autologin']) && $_COOKIE['autologin'] == 1) || (isset($_POST['autologin']) && $_POST['autologin'] == 1))
{
    $config['sess_expiration']      = 31536000;
    $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
}
else
{
    $config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
    $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
}
```